# read first 1000 characters of text file in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Am using the following command to read the first 1000 characters of a huge txt file.

```
    text = Input$(1000, 1)
```

problem is when I want to display a character in a textbox, it displays a newline character at the end (a reverseP) which I dont want.

The other option i have is to read the first 1000 characters using a Do-Until loop like the following. However, could not find a command to replace EOF(1).

```
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        text = text & textline
    Loop
```

can somebody provide any help with this ?

Comment: Have a look at the `Scripting.TextStream` you can use `.readline` to build a string until len>1000, then trim to size or reread a section of the last line? or just `.read(1000)`

Comment: `text = Replace(text, vbCr, ""): text = Replace(text, vbLf, "")`